# How to use Custom Translator service for new language pair

Tags: microsoft-translator

From [Customization page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/customization/), there is a description as follows:

> Custom Translator allows users to customize Microsoft Translator’s advanced neural machine translation for Translator’s supported neural translation languages".

zh-Hant (Chinese Traditional) is definitely supported by Microsoft Translator Neural Translation. But it's not available in the language pair candidate list when creating project in Custom Translator.

Does Custom Translator support building a custimized model for zh-Hant?

(If not, I also wonder why zh-Hant, one of supported neural translation languages,
is excluded in Custom Translator.)

Moreover, from "Custom Translator User Guide", it is said:

> Custom allows you to customize a language pair for a specific domain of terminology, or to build 
>   automatic translation for a language that is ***not yet supported by Microsoft Translator***.

I'd like to ask how to use Custom Translator to build a model for a language unsupported yet.
For example, how to create projects, how to choose lanugage pair in this case?

Answer (score 0):

We currently do not support zh-Hant in Custom Translator.  We are working on this language and will be adding support for it.

Custom Translator does not allow language pairs that are not supported by Microsoft.  The line you quoted was removed in the release documentation, but may have been present in the preview documentation.  If you do see it, could you please point it out to us?

Answer (score 0):

Chinese Traditional (zh-Hant) is now available in Custom Translator. You can select it as a language pair when creating a new project in the Custom Translator portal at https://portal.customtranslator.azure.ai/